# Select from table where timestamp is within x seconds

Tags: php, mysql, sql, time, timestamp

Am in some kind of mysql logic mess. I want to select rows from a table where the row timestamp is within the last 15 seconds of the current time.

More detail: timestamp field is generated using `php time()` function, am tryin to select if the timestamp is 15seconds or younger compared to the current timestamp

What I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM notifs WHERE `foo` = 'bar' AND `timestamp` > TIME(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 SECOND))");
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM notifs WHERE `foo` = 'bar' AND `timestamp` < unix_timestamp(NOW() - INTERVAL 15 SECOND)
```

They both return false positives. They give me rows i know are older than 15seconds ago. 
Please what could i be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM notifs
 WHERE foo = 'bar'
   AND timestamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 15 SECOND) 
                     AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
```